# regex for only numbers in string?

Tags: python, regex, integer, match, whitespace

I can't find the regex for strings containing only whitespaces or integers.
The string is an input from user on keyboard. It can contain everything but `\n` (but it doesn't matter I guess), but we can focus on ASCII since it's supposed to be English sentences
Here are some examples:

OK:

```
'1'
'2 3'
'   3 56 '
'8888888       333'
' 039'
```

not OK:

```
'a'
'4 e'
'874 1231 88 qqqq 99'
' shf ie sh f 8'
```

I have this which finds the numbers:

```
t = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', text)]
```

But I can't get the regex. My regex is currently `re.match(r'(\b\d+\b)+', text)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `re.match(r'\s*\d+(?:\s+\d+)*\s*$', s)`

Comment: What is text? If you search in a big text, what do you mean by 'containing only whitespaces or integers'?

Comment: It doesn't work :/ I'm still trying to figure out what yours is doing (but Dziekuje (half French & Polish guy))

Comment: text is a string that can contain everything you can enter on your keyboard (but \n, because it is a user input)

Comment: My regex above [works like this](https://regex101.com/r/NA70GC/1).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
>>> re.match(r'^([\s\d]+)$', text)
```

You need to put start (^) and end of line ($) characters in. Otherwise, the part of the string with the characters in will match, resulting in false positive matches

Comment: Note that `\s` matches `\n` and the `*` would also match no characters. I think you could also do without the capturing group `()`

Comment: The capturing group is not necessary, but I thought it would aid readability. I'll adjust `*` to `+`: thanks for your eagle eye.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this

```
^ *\d[\d ]*$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I8k3th/2)

The pattern requires at least one digit to be contained.

Comment: Also works, but @Mark 's answer is a bit shorter. However thank you for letting me discover this wonderful website for regex !!!

Comment: @YannDroy The difference is, that that my regex requires at laest one digit, the answer you mention also accepts empty strings or strings consisting only of white-space. Depends of course what fits your needs better.

Answer (score 4):

To match only a whitespace or a digit you could use:

[`^[ 0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/U1Qwhn/1)

That would match from the beginning of the string `^` one or more whitespaces or a digit using a character class `[ 0-9]+` until the end of the string `$`.