# I am reading from a csv file and ending up with a string within a string (something like this ' "88456" '). How do I extract the int value?

Tags: python, string, casting, integer, file-handling

I have tried using `int(targetVar)`, `int(int(targetVar))`, `int(float()`), map and I am stuck now.

My code looks like this :

```py
graph = []
nodes = []

file = open(path)
for line in file:
    source, target = line.split(',')

    nodes.append(int(source))
    nodes.append(int(target))
    graph.append(source, target)
```

Here *file* is a csv file with entries like "84424","276"

Comment: You can use regex to pull only the digits from the strings. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177227/12664040)

Comment: Python has a module for dealing with `csv` files! https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this:

```py
import csv

graph, nodes = [], []

with open("graph-nodes.csv", newline="") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # Discard the header (if there is one)
    next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        source, target = [int(item) for item in line]
        nodes.append(source)
        nodes.append(target)
        # Have to append a tuple if you want them together.
        graph.append((source, target))


print(f"{graph=}")
print(f"{nodes=}")
```

If I had this CSV file:

```
source,target
123,834
823,838
194,822
```

I would get this output:

```
graph=[(123, 834), (823, 838), (194, 822)]
nodes=[123, 834, 823, 838, 194, 822]
```